# Is the US government murdering "natural" doctors?

Tags: natural-remedies, healthcare, homeopathy

I keep seeing the claim of several recent suspicious deaths of "natural" doctors being passed around lately.  Often the claim is that they died "mysteriously" after visits by "Feds", etc.  I've tried to get to the bottom of this but all I find is more and more "conspiracy" type sites.

Anyway, here is the claim from a couple of sites...

[Source 1](http://thefreethoughtproject.com/5-holistic-heath-doctors-dead-5-missing-month-run-ins-feds/) [Source 2](http://www.healthnutnews.com/fifth-holistic-alternative-doctor-33-found-dead-in-florida-making-5-dead-and-5-more-missing-doctors/) [Source 3](http://freedomoutpost.com/2015/07/five-doctors-meet-untimely-and-suspicious-deaths-in-past-month-five-more-still-missing/) [Source 4](http://allnewspipeline.com/8_Disappeared_Dead_Doctors.php)

Etc.

Is there anything behind this?

Comment: It looks like the third source is just quoting the first two. The fourth one seems, erm, crazy, but at least seems to cite several different sources (in addition to your second source). I'm not entirely sure why this was downvoted, though it would help if you quoted some of the claims in the post and added the names of the sources (rather than just "Source 1", "Source 2", etc.) to make it more clear.

Comment: How would you possibly disprove this claim??

Comment: I suppose I should have made it more specific and asked if the specific people were murdered?  For instance, if those specific people listed in the articles could be proven to have been just straight up made up, that'd be proof that at least the specific claims are false.  Or if they do exist but friends and relatives have come forth and clarified the situations surrounding their deaths as non-suspicious?  Etc.

Comment: There's an epidemic of _patients_ of "natural" doctors getting or staying strangely sick... maybe that's worth looking into.

Comment: @AndrewHatsworth **Is there a [notable claim](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2506/what-is-a-notable-claim)** that these circumstances of death point to murder by govt agents or is it merely insinuated? Critics of homeopathic treatment for fatal diseases point out that it is ineffective, and perhaps fraudulent [see: ineffective treatment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_cancer_treatments).  Sometimes people who have committed serious frauds come under investigation and decide to kill themselves or are killed by a victim they defrauded.